# Finding 3rd point in Triangle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, math, trigonometry

Ok so I need to figure out in JavaScript how to plot a third point on a triangle. See diagram below.

A and B will be randomized points (may be positive or negative depending on where they fall relative to the 0,0 origin.)

thus A and B are known points (x and y).

I already figured out how to plot C based on A and B.

The distance between C and D I want control over. for example I want to say "The distance between C and D is now 20px... where is D?"

So I guess for example purposes we can say that the distance between C&D will be 20px. That means I have CD and CB, but not DB. I also know C(x,y) and B(x,y).

I need to find D now... I'm not a math mind so please explain it to me like I'm 5. I've googled it multiple times, attempted to use multiple examples, and I'm still lost... For example: I saw some equations with phi mentioned.. what is phi? How do I use phi in JavaScript terms, etc...

summary:

```
A(x,y) is known (randomized)
B(x,y) is known (randomized)
C(x,y) is known (midpoint of AB)
CB is known (using distance formula)
CD = 20 pixels (or whatever I set it to).
DB = ???
D(x,y) = ???
```

Here's what I have so far, but it's probably wrong..

```
var Aeh = {x:50, y:75};
    var Bee = {x:300, y:175};
    var Cee = {x:0, y:0};
    var Dee = {x:0, y:0};

    window.onload = function(){ 
         refreshPoints();
         solveForC();
    } 
    function refreshPoints(){
        TweenLite.set("#pointA", {x:Aeh.x, y:Aeh.y});
        TweenLite.set("#pointB", {x:Bee.x, y:Bee.y});
        TweenLite.set("#pointC", {x:Cee.x, y:Cee.y});
        TweenLite.set("#pointD", {x:Dee.x, y:Dee.y});
    }
    function solveForC() {
        Cee.x = (Bee.x + Aeh.x)/2;
        Cee.y = (Bee.y + Aeh.y)/2;
        refreshPoints();
        solveForD();
    }
    function solveForD() {
        // Dee.x = AB * Cos(Φ) + x_1
        // Dee.y = AB * Sin(Φ) + y_1

        Dee.x = (Cee.x+Bee.x/2) * Math.cos((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2) + Cee.x;
        Dee.y = (Cee.y+Bee.y/2) * Math.sin((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2) + Cee.y;

        refreshPoints();
    }
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: I tried the code I posted above based on some equations other people have posted online. I'm kind of shooting in the dark though, because I don't understand the math.

Comment: You need to know the distance between C and either A or B, unless C is the midpoint of AB? And also we need to know which side of AB D is, otherwise there would be two solutions.

Comment: C is the midpoint, so I can easily find the distance between C & B.  I want to be able randomly flip D to either side, so, I'm not sure how that would work.. I guess I need both solutions..

summary:

A is known (randomized)

B is known (randomized)

C = is known (midpoint of AB)

CB is known

CD = 20 pixels (or whatever I set it to).

DB = ???

Answer (score 2):

You have A, B and C (the midpoint), you know the distance from C to D is set (say at 20), and the line from C to D is at right angles to the line from A to B. You can find two solutions for D using this. The simplest way to understand is to find the angle of the line from A to B, and use that help calculate D.

```
var angleAB = Math.atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x);
// to get the angle of the line from C to D, add 90 degrees
// in radians, that is Math.PI / 2
var angleCD = angleAB + Math.PI / 2;

// now you can calculate one of D's solutions
// the 20 represents your distance from C to D, and can be changed if desired.
DeeOne.x = C.x + 20 * Math.cos(angleCD);
DeeOne.y = C.y + 20 * Math.sin(angleCD);

// a second solution can be found by going in the other direction from C
DeeTwo.x = C.x - 20 * Math.cos(angleCD);
DeeTwo.y = C.x - 20 * Math.sin(angleCD);
```

There might be ways to cut out some of this calculation if all you need is a certain distance (etc) from the diagram. Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!!! It worked.. however I should note that Math.atan2 returned "NaN" but Math.tan seemed to work.. is there an important difference between the two or will "tan" work for me the same way?

Comment: `atan` and `atan2` are pretty much equivalent... I think there might be some cases (when A and B have the same x coordinate) that `atan2` will work but `atan` will break. But if it's working that's great! If you want to be really careful, make sure it works when A and B have the same x-coordinate.

Comment: Oh, I just spotted why atan2 is being funny. atan takes a single argument with num / denom, but atan2 expects them seperately. So I should have written `Math.atan2((B.y - A.y), (B.x - A.x))` rather than `Math.atan2((B.y - A.y) / (B.x - A.x))`. I'll edit if I can...

Answer (score 0):

#### A slightly quicker and more accurate alternative solution.

Function finds the point `dist` from the midpoint of the line `A`, `B`.

`D` is left of the line `AB` if `left = 1` (default) else `D` is right of the line if `left = -1`

```
function findD(A, B, dist, left = 1){ // if left = 1 the D is left of the line AB 
    const nx = B.x - A.x;
    const ny = B.y - A.y;
    dist /= Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny) * left;
    return {
        x : A.x + nx / 2 - ny * dist, 
        y : A.y + ny / 2 + nx * dist
    }
}
```

You may be tempted to replace the `Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny)` with `Math.hypot(nx,ny)` and save 2 multiplications and an addition. But `hypot` is agonizingly slow. With the function using `sqrt` doing 10million a second when I use `hypot` that drops down to 2Million. Also timed the other answer (optimised to be fair) and that peaked at 3.4Million solutions a second.

For javascript using `atan2` and `sin` and `cos` is not that much of an issue as the 64bit double precision float make the error introduced by these functions insignificant, in the range ±1e-14 * length of longest side, but the error can be reduced (a little) if you avoid these functions