# Derive third vertex in JavaScript triangle calculation

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, cad

I'm trying to draw a triangle for CAD modelling using JavaScript and Tinkercad's API. I'm taking as inputs 2 of the angles and the length of one side. I almost have it working, but my math must be wrong. Can you spot where it's going off the rails? Clearly, the generated triangle is not equilateral, even though I have 60 and 60 for the angle inputs.
[image: Wedge By Angles Screenshot]

Here is the code I have:

```
function process(params) {
  var h = params.height || 20;
  var angleA = params.angleA || 60;
  var angleB = params.angleB || 60;
  var angleC = 180 - (angleA + angleB);
  var sideA = params.sideA || 20;

  // TODO: account for invalid input > than 180?

  var sinA = Math.sin(degToR(angleA));
  var sinB = Math.sin(degToR(angleB));
  var sinC = Math.sin(degToR(angleC));

  var ratio = sideA / sinA;
  var sideB = ratio * sinB; // length of side B
  var sideC = ratio * sinC; // length of side C

  // Find vertex C
  var vertexC = {};
  vertexC.x = Math.round(Math.cos(angleC * Math.PI / 180) * sideC + 0);
  vertexC.y = Math.round(Math.sin(angleC * Math.PI / 180) * sideC + sideA);

  // Build triangle
  var path = new Path2D();
  path.moveTo(0,0);
  path.lineTo(0, sideA);
  path.lineTo(vertexC.x, vertexC.y);
  path.close();

  // "Extrude" to CAD's third dimension
  return Solid.extrude([path], h);
}

function degToR(x){
  return x / 180 * Math.PI;
}
```

I have tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152098/finding-3rd-point-in-triangle-using-javascript) to my inputs, but I am missing something.

Comment: Show what vertexes, sides and angles you designate A, B, C. It looks inconsistent.